# How to make top tab bar inside 1 item tab bar controller to show multiple view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have tab bar controller that show some items.
And one item in tab bar controller have multiple view controller that show by a top tab bar.
I already tried to make it with segment control and multiple container view but it didn't worked properly.

This is the storyboard that I want to make [StoryboardExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYuHD.png)

I want the three view controllers in the right show in View Controller 2 in item tab bar and control by the top tab bar.
So, its like Activity Tab in Youtube Application that have top tab bar with item Shared and Notifications. 
[Shared View in Youtube Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEkr.jpg) , 
[Notification View in Youtube Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLsMN.jpg)

**Edit**

This is the code to change the view from segment control,

```
@objc func changeGroup(sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    if sender.numberOfSegments == 3
    {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0 :
            if self.groupView.isHidden == true
            {
                self.groupView.isHidden = false
            }
            if self.inspirationView.isHidden == false
            {
                self.inspirationView.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.pesantrenView.isHidden == false
            {
                self.pesantrenView.isHidden = true
            }

        case 1:
            if self.groupView.isHidden == false
            {
                self.groupView.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.inspirationView.isHidden == true
            {
                self.inspirationView.isHidden = false
            }
            if self.pesantrenView.isHidden == false
            {
                self.pesantrenView.isHidden = true
            }

        case 2:
            if self.groupView.isHidden == false
            {
                self.groupView.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.inspirationView.isHidden == false
            {
                self.inspirationView.isHidden = true
            }
            if self.pesantrenView.isHidden == true
            {
                self.pesantrenView.isHidden = false
            }

        default :
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post some of your code , what you have done so far

Comment: **I already tried to make it with segment control and multiple container view but it didn't worked properly.** What didn't work for you ?

Comment: @Tej Hai tej, that is the method that I use to switch the container view in that item tab

Comment: @PrashantTukadiyaThe tableview delegate and datasource in the container view controller didn't work properly. Sometimes the data show, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a custom tab bar controller. Follow this lead and you'll be home: https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Creating-a-Custom-Tab-Bar

here you should know, they create the tab bar manually with a UIView and Buttons I have implemented a basic version with a native tab bar here: https://github.com/zameerascentic/customTabBarNative

You should note (differs from that tutorial):

1. Tab bar is positioned bottom here, you can move anywhere you want
2. View controllers are created seperately and loaded into a UIView
   called ContainerView on tab bar item select delegate
3. Check the tab bar tags, it will be 0,1 etc, because it will be the
   indexes of the viewControllers array - all our view controllers are
   loaded into an array for easy reference.
4. ViewControllers are given storyboardIDs to be called by tab bar

Comment: Thank you, it helps